# reuse table data in round robin manner

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

Let us say I have some data I would like to repeat N times. A naive approach would be this:

```
  IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Data', 'U') IS NOT NULL
      DROP TABLE dbo.Data

    CREATE TABLE Data
    (
        DataId INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        DataValue NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL
    )

    INSERT INTO Data (DataId, DataValue)
        SELECT 1, 'Value1' UNION ALL
        SELECT 2, 'Value2' UNION ALL
        SELECT 3, 'Value3' UNION ALL
        SELECT 4, 'Value4' UNION ALL
        SELECT 5, 'Value5' 

    DECLARE @RowsRequired INT
    DECLARE @Counter INT
    DECLARE @NumberOfRows INT

    SET @RowsRequired = 22

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempData') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TempData
    CREATE TABLE #TempData
    (
        Id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
        DataValue NVARCHAR(MAX)
    )

    SELECT @NumberOfRows = COUNT(*) FROM Data
    SET @Counter = 1

    WHILE @RowsRequired > 0
    BEGIN

        INSERT INTO #TempData
        SELECT DataValue FROM Data WHERE DataId = @Counter

        SET @Counter = @Counter + 1
        SET @RowsRequired = @RowsRequired - 1
        IF(@Counter > @NumberOfRows)
            BEGIN
                SET @Counter = 1
            END
    END

    SELECT * FROM #TempData
```

Here @RowsRequired determines how many rows are required. Could this be rephrased in a set based form? Thanks.

Here is a [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4d94a/1) with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
DECLARE @RowsRequired INT = 22

;WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT DataId, DataValue, ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY DataId ORDER BY DataId) sort
  FROM DATA
  CROSS JOIN
  (
    SELECT TOP (@RowsRequired) 0 d
    FROM master..spt_values
  ) d
)
SELECT TOP (@RowsRequired) ROW_NUMBER() over (order by sort),  DataValue
FROM CTE
ORDER BY sort, 1
```

Comment: Thanks t-clausen.dk. Looks great. Is there a way to avoid the insert into #TempData and show an id based on ROW_NUMBER() ([1 ... 22] in this case)?

Comment: I know - did this but how do I get the running number up to 22 (not to original table's id) in this particular scenario? In my question I used an identity(1,1) column in the #TempData table ...

Comment: If I do this I only get one DataValue (the first one)

Comment: When I run your now adapted example I am getting discontinuous numbers larger than 22, which probably stem from  master..spt_values.

Comment: Did you have a chance to look into this?

Comment: @csetzkorn been very busy today. Script fixed

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and worked for me.

```
declare @requiredrows int

set @requiredrows = 22;

declare @foreachrow int
select @foreachrow = @requiredrows / Count(*) from Data;

select top (@requiredrows) * from
(
select *, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by dataId order by number) rno
from Data
Cross Join master..spt_values
) A
where rno <= @foreachrow + 1
```

Hope it will help.